# Reading multiple values from a file with name value pair

Tags: java, list, file

```
public String readvaluesFromFile(String PassingAnameString) {
    File myfile = new File("src/main/resources/file.txt");
    FileInputStream myFileInput = new FileInputStream(errorFile);
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(myFileInput);
    myFileInput.close();
    Enumeration<Object> filenameKeys = properties.keys();
    while (filenameKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
        String fileValues = properties.getProperty(PassingAnameString);
        return "Reference Name: " + filenameKeys + " : " + fileValues;
    }
    return "There was a problem.";
}
```

I have a function that passes a string of names to a function which
   returns the respective value of those names from a text file.

For instance. text file contains: name=value name=value name=value

Function 1 passes a string of "name, name" to function 2, which reads
   the file. I am unable to figure out how to get the file to read
   multiple names and return the respective values. Any input?

Function2 above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accept a variable number of Strings and return an equal number of String values.
  Try this:

```
public String[] readvaluesFromFile(String... PassingManyStrings) {
    File myfile = new File("src/main/resources/file.txt");
    FileInputStream myFileInput = new FileInputStream(errorFile);
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(myFileInput);
    myFileInput.close();

    String[] toReturn = new String[ PassingManyStrings.length ];
    int i=0;
    for(String oneProp: PassingManyStrings){
        toReturn[i++] = properties.getProperty(oneProp);
        if( toReturn[i++] == null)
              toReturn[i++] = "There was a problem.";
        else
              toReturn[i++] = "Reference Name: " + oneProp + " : " + toReturn[i++];
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```